# Can't pass environment variable from GitHub Actions to nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, environment-variables, github-actions

To be short I have an Angular app where I have env config. I decided to write a build number directly into the field of that config file.

So I made a script that is being run by Node after checkout and before the actual build step and writes a build number into that file. This is a fragment of my GitHub Actions workflow yml for it:

```
        run: |
          npm install
          node setbuildnumber.js build=${{ env.GITHUB_ACTION }}
          npm run build-demo
```

The script works when I test it separately. And it runs in Actions as I see. But after I build and deploy my Angular app, I see my build number is `undefined`.

Before writing a question, I looked through Stack Overflow topics and only found a variant where it was recommended to write a variable value to file and then read it with Node script. But that solution looks unclean.

Comment: Did you configure the env variable before the steps section? Just to try print the value of process.env to check the exact env values that github action pass to your nodejs script. Be careful if you have some sensible variable

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning there is a convention to follow for naming env variable. In your example you used `env.GITHUB_ACTION` but the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#naming-conventions-for-environment-variables) states that variables names can't start with the `GITHUB_` prefix.

Comment: It's a native variable https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables

Comment: Make a step `echo ${{ env.GITHUB_ACTION }}`, you will see it in the build log

Comment: I have the same problem, but with Python 3.8 and passing a Personal Access Token to the script. It passes an empty string for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure now that arguments aren't being passed into the node script. So I've written the variable name into the temporary file, read it, written it into the angular environment configs recursively and deleted the file after all. This is the only thing that worked for me practically.